# Ubuntu 12.04 fails modprobe Tainted

Tags: 12.04, modprobe

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on an old laptop and I am getting errors - Black screen with many lines of text.  Pertinent one appears to be Modprobe Tainted with a lot of debugging info - registers, stack, and call trace.  I would post it but I am not sure where it is located and how to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old, I wanted to post a response since I found it looking up my own problem with a Gateway MX 6440.

I received this error due to a Broadcom Wireless NIC in the system. I ended up physically removing the card from the laptop (laptop dosn't have the option to disable it via a hardware switch/button or the BIOS).

I was able to install Xubuntu 13.04 i386 without an issue, and then installed the [b43-fwcutter](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) package and was able to plug in and use the Broadcom wireless NIC.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to install Xubuntu 13.04 on an HP Pavilion zx5040us latop, and I too got the "modprobe tainted" error and resulting stack dump.  I ran `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` and sure enough, the system has a Broadcom wireless LAN adapter.

Lots of laptops out there use Broadcom wireless LAN adapters. I've run across several of them.

I found this page to be very helpful:
http://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

And this one:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

Installing the b43 driver before installing xubuntu didn't work.  I'm going to have to find a page that shows me how to disassemble the laptop and remove the wireless adapter.